# Angular Directive Call function from own scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building an `Angular` directive which displays a list of items. The list of items is provided by a function from that directive's own `scope`. Below is a basic version of what I'm doing (`listOpts` needs to be a fn and isn't static data). When the template is compiled `listOpts` is not evaluated, so the template returns an empty `ul`. When I place the `listOpts` fn in the parent `controller` it evaluates it. But I do not want to put the `listOpts` function in the controller because of SRP (single responsibility principle); the `listOpts` function *belongs* to the `list` directive and not the `controller`. I must be misunderstanding something about how directives work or when the template is compiled? Should I be putting the `listOpts` fn in the `controller` fn with the directive?

```
@app.directive "list", () ->
  restrict: "E"
  link: (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) ->
    scope.listOpts = ()->
      return [1,2,3]

  template: "
    <ul ng-repeat='item in listOpts()'>
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    <ul>
  "
```

Comment: ng-repeat isn't designed to work like this, use a static list and change the list when needed. if you still want to attempt this then simply adding a scope: {} to your directive should isolate it for you.

Comment: @Delta I don't think that's the problem. As I said having a function provide the array works when the function is in the parent scope, but not from within the directive. As I also said I can't use a static list. And I already tried adding an isolated scope, I think the problem is me not understanding exactly how template compiling for directives works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code provided seems to work as is:

http://plnkr.co/edit/r589eFGZm8MOTk94GJtk?p=preview

just modified to use regular JS, what's the issue here exactly, can you reproduce the problem in the plnkr.

```
.directive("list", function() {
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl){ scope.listOpts = function(){return [1,2,3];}},
  template: "<ul ng-repeat='item in listOpts()'><li>{{item}}</li><ul>"
  }
})
```

Comment: coffeescript indentation error...embarrassed...thank you. (spent about 4 hours trying to figure this out)

Comment: ah no worries... I don't know coffeescript really so had to translate and just try it out, glad you got it working might want to post your fix/answer if you can in case someone else does the same with coffeescript